# MDX in Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Does anybody working with MDX Queries on SharePoint ? Any experience or documentations how to implement this ?

I want a MDX query with a connection to a cube and get the result in html...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible in SharePoint. I would suggest to use a simple REST/JSON WCF WebService to query the cube, which you could call by jQuery for example and render the result in the way you want.

Other way could be to use a WebPart or custom application page to query a cube and show the result.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - When I use JSON then i need also a connection to my database, or ? That is possible from SharePoint ? With C# ?

Comment: Yes, when you create a WebService which returns JSON, then you are able to read the result frm this JSON for example with jQuery. But the logic for the query and additionally the DB connection etc. lays in the WebService Logic which could be written in C# oder VB.Net. Look at ADO.Net for DB Connectivity...

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know this is not possible. SharePoint doesn't have native methods to query cubes with MDX.

Possibilities are (depending on your SharePoint version en licenses):

- Reporting services integrations. SSRS can query cubes and present it in a report. You might be able to use that as an input to your HTML
- Excel Services is able to connect to cubes
- PerformancePoint

If you haven't checked any of these out, please do so and find out if they meet your requirements.